# UITextField floatValue loading Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, xib

I have a ViewController (VC1) that instantiate another one ViewController (VC2).
VC2 has some iVar linked with IBOutlets. When I link a UITextField to its ivar, the app crashes during the loading of the nib with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I don't really know why it happen.
Below there is the code:

VC1:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    multiplaView = [[MultiplaView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MultiplaView" bundle:nil];
    multiplaView.delegate = self;
}
```

VC2:

```
@interface MultiplaView ()
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *bonus;
    IBOutlet UILabel *totalStake;
    IBOutlet UILabel *maxWinPot;
    IBOutlet UITextField *singleImport;
    IBOutlet UITextField *multiImport;
}

@end

@implementation MultiplaView

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        // Something...
    }
    return self;
}
```

These are the Outlets:

[image: Outlets links]

### EDIT:

MultiplaView is a UIViewController (sorry for the bad name...). I don't call anywhere the floatValue methods in that object.
When I remove the outlets links on the UITextFields it doesn't crash...
**The question is: why the compiler execute a `floatValue` request on the UITextField during the nib-loading??**

### RESOLVED:

It was the custom setter method on the textFields. I was thinking that, declaring them as ivar and linking them with the outlets, Xcode shouldn't create automatic setter methods... So Xcode read my methods as setter and it called them during the loading of the nib.

As you can see, this is the code:

```
-(void)setSingleImport: (float)importWithoutComma
{
    float import = importWithoutComma / 100.0;
    NSString *importStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"€ %.2f", import];
    singleImport.text = importStr;
}
```

I changed the name of the method in `-setSingleImportValue:` and now it works

Comment: Your error suggest that you are trying to call `floatValue` on your `UITextField` object, which is a method it does not respond to. Maybe you are confusing, and want to call it on the `text` property of the `UITextField` object. for example (using your `singleImport` `UITextField` object) `[singleImport.text floatValue]`.

Comment: There's no method that call floatValue in MultiplaView...

Comment: If you unlink your `UITextField` outlets, does it occur?

Comment: Are you sure `VC2` is the cause of the crash? If you don't alloc-init it, does it stop crashing?

Comment: I'm sure that is the process of nib-loading that causes the crash. I tried in many ways to initialize this view, but it always crash with this error, always with the TextField Outlets linked... When I remove these links, it'll not crash.

Comment: Can you please show the init method of `VC2`

Comment: @AMI289 I resolved as I wrote in the first post. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can load xib:

```
MultiplaView * multiplaView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MultiplaView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
multiplaView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I also did so, but it doesn't change the result. Error. I tried clean up the build folder and I analyzed the XML, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the MultiplaView nib using correct method, use this method

```
MultiplaView * multiplaView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MultiplaView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: MultiplaView is a UIViewController, not only a simple UIView. I tried also initializing the controller and loading on self.view the nib. Always error occurred